# Replacing multiple special characters

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to get rid of multiple special characters that might show up in  a specific column and replace it with a space but I keep getting this error when I try to write my file to an excel document.

```
Exception: Invalid Excel character '[]:*?/\' in sheetname 'AL DINTE LASA/JACKY'S'
```

I have already tried the below but it is not working but I dont know why that should get rid of multiple special characters and then replace it with an underscore.

```
 df['Name'].replace(["/''//'-[]:*?/\\/#",'_'],regex=True)
```

I dont know what else to try I cant seem to get around this error, am I just not using df.replace correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in the spreadsheet data itself - it is in the name of the spreadsheet. Specifically, the slash is not allowed in the sheetname. You can change the name to "AL DINTE LASA-JACKY'S" and it should work fine.

Comment: So am I not able to change it in the code I have? Like how can I use the code I have and specify if their are any slashes in the Name column substitute it out for a space or underscore?

Comment: As far as I know, the str.replace function only replaces things one for one, and doesn't handle regex expressions. I could be wrong - can you point me to the docs for this? Otherwise, you need to import the 're' module and use it for handling regexes. With the normal replace, you would use `df['Name'].replace('/', '_')

Comment: No your absolutely right I just wasnt understanding that I could write out all the special characters I wanted to get rid of I could only use one this is what I used df['N_INSURED_1'] = df['N_INSURED_1'].str.replace('/','_') you were right it was the / that was giving me such a problem. Thank you Laughing Vergil.